# Passing an empty array as default value of an optional parameter

Tags: c#, default-value, optional-parameters

How does one define a function that takes an optional array with an empty array as default?

```
public void DoSomething(int index, ushort[] array = new ushort[] {},
 bool thirdParam = true)
```

results in:

Default parameter value for 'array' must be a compile-time constant.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. It is specific in asking how to set a default value for an array, not a string. There is a real difference in approaches

Answer (score 163, accepted):

You can't create compile-time constants of object references.

The only valid compile-time constant you can use is `null`, so change your code to this:

```
public void DoSomething(int index, ushort[] array = null,
  bool thirdParam = true)
```

And inside your method do this:

```
array = array ?? new ushort[0];
```

*(from comments)* From C# 8 onwards you can also use the shorter syntax:

```
array ??= new ushort[0];
```

Comment: yes, that does come to mind, except passing null is not the same as an empty array.  I was hoping for a way to do it without having to dress the param inside the method.  The bit about ompile-time constants of object references makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: that throws ArgumentNullException, anybody knows why?

Comment: Yes, you're not fixing the case that you are actually receiving `null`, did you use the second statement from my answer?

Comment: I just wanted to mention that C# 8 now allows a prettier syntax. `array ??= new ushort[0];`

Comment: Null-coalescing assignment operator `??=` is available in C# 8

Comment: Probably you can consider `Array.Empty<ushort>()`

Comment: And now tweak that for `record`s ;) ... it is annoying ;)

Answer (score 32):

If you can make the array the last argument you could also do this:

```
public void DoSomething(int index, bool wasThirdParam = true, params ushort[] array)
```

The compiler will automatically pass an empty array if it is not specified, and you get the added flexibility to either pass an array as a single argument or put the elements directly as variable length arguments to your method.

Answer (score 8):

I know it's an old question, and whilst this answer doesn't directly solve how to get around the limitations imposed by the compiler, method overloading is an alternative:

```
   public void DoSomething(int index, bool thirdParam = true){
        DoSomething(index, new ushort[] {}, thirdParam);
   }

   public void DoSomething(int index, ushort[] array, bool thirdParam = true){

      ...
   }
```

Comment: I am not sure whether a compiler could then infer and optimize a mutual recursion instead of an usual *(though yes, I know e.g. there is an option `-foptimize-sibling-calls` in g++, but it is C++, I am not sure whether C# compilers can it)*.