# set initialized arrays as parameters in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, methods, parameters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [passing an empty array as default value of optional parameter in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480382/passing-an-empty-array-as-default-value-of-optional-parameter-in-c-sharp)

This code is correct in C# 4.0

```
static void SomeMethod(int x, int y = 5, int z = 7)
{
}
SomeMethod(1);
```

but when applied on arrays it gives me errors

```
private static void diagonalFill(int[,] a,int[] fillType = {0,-1},int[] diagFill = {-1,1})
    {

    }
    diagonalFill(array);
```

Could anyone show me the right way? 10x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default parameter values are not possible with complex reference values. The first one works because the parameters are primitives <strike>that are stored on the stack and are copied by value</strike>. Arrays are complex reference values so they must first be allocated before they can appear as parameters.

**Edit:**
@Henk Holterman's comment is well taken. I don't have direct knowledge of whether the stack or heap come into play on this so this information is either mistaken or misleading. The primary criteria I am aware of is that only [primitives types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228360%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) can be used. From [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx),

> A default value must be one of the following types of expressions:
>
> 1. a constant expression;
> 2. an expression of the form new ValType(), where ValType is a value
>      type, such as an enum or a struct;
> 3. an expression of the form default(ValType), where ValType is a value
>      type.

The "primitives" list link above has been modified for 2010 to be called "built-in" types. It can be [found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx).

Comment: strings are also reference types and they can be used as defaults just fine. And the stack really doesn't play a role here.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Fair enough. That was supplemental to a conversation I had with someone and I couldn't find anything to back it up (plus it what you say sounds reasonable). I've stricken it and provided links to to support my statement that the parameters must be primitives (or as they are now called in 2010 - built-in types).

Answer (score 3):

A default parameter value must be a compile time constant, so you can't do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use initializers as default.

You could use:

```
private static void diagonalFill(int[,] a, 
       int[] fillType = null, 
       int[] diagFill = null)
{
  if (fillType == null)
     fillType = new int[] {0,-1};

  if (diagFill == null)
     diagFill = new int[] {-1,1};

  ... 
}
```

Comment: this solution of course depends on null not being an option that is ever going to be passed as a parameter.