# optional array Parameter in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [passing an empty array as default value of optional parameter in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480382/passing-an-empty-array-as-default-value-of-optional-parameter-in-c-sharp)

I have a method that looks like below. Currently, the parameter `tags` is NOT optional

```
void MyMethod(string[] tags=null)
{
   tags= tags ?? new string[0];
   /*More codes*/
}
```

I want to make parameter `tags` optional, as per `c#` , to make a parameter optional you can set a default value in method signature. I tried the following hacks but none worked.

**Code that didn't work - 1**

```
void MyMethod(string[] tags=new string[0]){}
```

**Code that didn't work - 2**

```
void MyMethod(string[] tags={}){}
```

Please suggest what I am missing.

---

I have already seen this question:

[Passing an empty array as default value of an optional parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480382/passing-an-empty-array-as-default-value-of-optional-parameter-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480382/passing-an-empty-array-as-default-value-of-optional-parameter-in-c-sharp

Comment: in this particular case, you might get away with C#3.0 compatible `void MyMethod(params string[] tags)`

Comment: What's wrong with `tags = tags ?? new string[0];` anyway? And if you have already seen the question, the accepted answer clearly states that you *can't* set a default value with the C# 4 syntax, and that you can use the `??` operator instead as you are doing.

Comment: `tags` looks optional enough to me in your original method.

Comment: What's wrong with `string[] tags=null` exactly? It does work.

Comment: @boltclock with `tags = tags ?? new string[0];` tags is not optional.

Comment: @Rusi Nova: It is optional if you set a default value of `null`.

Comment: @RusiNova, we might be using a different definition of optional. To be clear, as far as the language is concerned, `void Foo(string[] tags = null)` indeed makes supplying the argument *optional* for the caller. Whether or not the null is *usable* inside your method is a different matter.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) for optional arguments says:

> A default value must be one of the following types of expressions:
>
> - a constant expression;
> - an expression of the form `new ValType()`, where `ValType` is a value type, such as an `enum` or a `struct`;
> - an expression of the form `default(ValType)`, where `ValType` is a value type.

Since `new string[0]` is neither a constant expression nor a `new` statement followed by a value type, it cannot be used as a default argument value.

The first code excerpt in your question is indeed a good workaround:

```
void MyMethod(string[] tags = null)
{
   tags = tags ?? new string[0];
   // Now do something with 'tags'...
}
```

Comment: +1 And the workaround is suggested in the accepted answer to the duplicate question.

Comment: This is correct but if you use MyMethod(params Object[] parameterName) You can omit the params array and the compiler will pass an empty array for you. MyMethod() works just fine.

Comment: Upvoted for linking and in-lining the relevant authoritative documentation. "Teach a man to fish..."

Answer (score 5):

not sure if i am getting it right this works.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                TestMe();

        }


private static void TestMe(string[] param = null)
    {
        if (param == null)
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("its empty");
        }
    }
```

also the value of param has to be compile time constant