# C# set default argument, string array (string[])

Tags: c#, parameters, default

I have googled some examples of C# default string parameters and found that is like this.

**string Exceptions =  "John"**

I need to set the default value for a string [] but y haven't found how can I set an string array as default value for a C# method.

```
static int startapp(string Source, string Destination, string[] Exceptions = { "John", "Paul", "Mary" })
            {
                 //do something
            }
```

Comment: I think it's not allowed to use array literals in default parameters. I usually set them to null, and then if the value is null set the default value in the method body.

Comment: Found [this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607146/method-parameter-array-default-value) It seems to pertain to what you're trying to do.

Comment: That answer does look like a better way to do it. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this had to be a comment but I  don't have enough reputation to add a comment. What you are probably looking for is this answer

[optional array Parameter in C# [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213753/optional-array-parameter-in-c-sharp)

it says (from the docs)

```
A default value must be one of the following types of expressions:

    a constant expression;

    an expression of the form new ValType(), where ValType is a value type, such as an enum or a struct;

    an expression of the form default(ValType), where ValType is a value type.
```

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN

> A default value must be one of the following types of expressions:
>    - a constant expression;
>    - an expression of the form new ValType(), where ValType is a value type, such as an enum or a struct;
>    - an expression of the form default(ValType), where ValType is a value type.

In your case `string[]` is a reference type.
For reference types default value is always `null`

Visual Studio proved an explanation when you try to initialize new array as default type:

> Default parameter value must be a compile-time constant