# Syntax for declaring optional string array parameter

Tags: vb.net, parameters, optional-parameters

What is the proper syntax for declaring an option parameter of type `String()`; means how do I assign it a default value of empty array (not `Nothing`):

```
Function SomeFunc(id as Integer, name as String, Optional values() As String = ???)
```

I tried with `{}` but it doesn't accept that, saying "A constant expression is required", which also means it won't accept anything like `New String()`.

Comment: [Passing an empty array as default value of an optional parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480382/passing-an-empty-array-as-default-value-of-an-optional-parameter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hi You can Try This..

```
function example(optional ByVal arr1() as System.Array = nothing)
```

Comment: Thanks but you probably missed that I want to assign it an empty array, not `Nothing`.

Comment: I figured out that this is currently not possible to do what I want. Passing `Nothing` is my only option here, so I'll mark this as answer.