# Instantiate an empty string[] as a parameter to make it optional

Tags: c#

I have something super similar to:

```cs
private void Method(string[] Parameters= {})
{
    // execute code here
}
```

The issue I run into here is an error stating:

> invalid expression term '{'

so if I remove the `'= {}'` I no longer have an optional `string[]` as a parameter. I need to have a `string[]` as an optional parameter.

Let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480382/passing-an-empty-array-as-default-value-of-an-optional-parameter

Comment: @whoever closed my question, that one you marked as duplicate was before 4.0 was released. Im certain there is an implementation of something better in 4.0.

Comment: Dear LOGAN. I was the one that initially tried to answer your question and after better search marked it as duplicate. From my narrow knowledge I believe this holds for new versions of .NET. In any case if you are certain there exists a better implementation why not try to search before asking?

Comment: @LOGANr18 If you, or anyone else, comes up with a better solution to the problem than what's already on the existing question, you/they are free to post a new answer with a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply null as the default value for an optional string array.

```
  private void Method(string[] Parameters = null)
  {
        if (Parameters == null)
        {
            // optional parameter not passed in
        }
        else
        {
            // do work with the parameter
        }
  }
```